# How can I loop through this array inside this instance of my mongoose model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    post:[
        {postId: String},
        {commentComponent: [
            {comment: [String]},
      ]}
]

})
const Posts = mongoose.model('Posts', postSchema)
```

This is the definition of the schema for modeling the mongodb

```
const postLinks = await getPostLinks();    
const posts =  new Posts({
        for (let i = 0; i < postLinks.length; i++) {     
            const comment =  await getComment(postLinks[i]) // here it takes postLinks as a paramaeter to get an array of comment
            post: [
                {postId: postLinks[i]},
                {commentComponent: [
                    {comment: comment}
                ]}
            ]
        }
    })
const result = await posts.save()
```

is there a way of iterating inside this instance because the for loop here is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an object to the `Posts` constructor with a property called `post` (which probably should be called `posts`, but will keep the original name below), and for this property, you need to specify an array.

This array can be built by using [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
const post = await Promise.all(
    postLinks.map(async (postLink) => {
        const comment = await getComment(postLink);

        return {
            postId: postLink,
            commentComponent: [{ comment }],
        };
    })
);

const posts =  new Posts({ post });
const result = await posts.save();
```

But if you prefer, you can use the traditional for-loop (more similar to what you were trying to do) as well:

```
const post = [];
for (let i = 0; i < postLinks.length; i++) {  
    const comment = await getComment(postLinks[i]);

    post.push({
        postId: postLinks[i]},
        commentComponent: [{ comment }]
    });
}

const posts =  new Posts({ post });
const result = await posts.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code example I am not certain what you are attempting to do. When using a Model and trying to create you can think of as a new singular record. If you are trying to insert many links into a single record I would suggest comma separating them then inserting that into your MongoDB.

But you cannot iterate inside your Posts class like that.

If I were you I would set up my file something like this:

file: models/Post.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: [true, 'Please add some text']
  },
  link: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please add link']
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

Then create a controller js file
file: controllers/posts.js:

```
const Post = require('../models/Post');

// @desc    Add Post
// @route   POST /api/v1/posts
// @access  Public
exports.addPost = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    // get post data from the request
    // mongo returns a promise so await on it
    const post = await Post.create(req.body);

    return res.status(201).json({
      success: true,
      data: post
    }); 
  } catch (err) {
    if(err.name === 'ValidationError') {
      const messages = Object.values(err.errors).map(val => val.message);

      return res.status(400).json({
        success: false,
        error: messages
      });
    } else {
      return res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        error: 'Server Error'
      });
    }
  }
}
```

then in your router file, you can use your controller:
routes/post.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { addPost } = require('../controllers/posts');

router
  .route('/')
  .post(addPost);

module.exports = router;
```